# Reverse switch case statement

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

I want to reverse the code inside switch block rather doing it my self (it seems to make no sense to me)
ex:

```
{            string name = Console.ReadLine();
             string s = null;
             for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (name[i])
                {
                    case 'a':
                        s += '1';break;
                    case 'q':
                        s += '2'; break;
                 }
            }
}
```

How to make it reversed to act like this:

```
                    case '1':
                        s += 'a';break;
                    case '2':
                        s += 'q'; break;
```

My code contains more than 30 statements for each character.

Comment: 1. Create a `Dictionary`. 2. ??????? 3. PROFIT!!!!11

Comment: This is good because you realized there must be a better way.

Comment: doing it with a switch in the first place was wrong. You should have a pair of char arrays that map from one to the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Dictionary<char, char>` for the mapping (in fact you could create two for performance reasons and ease of use), or a simple list type with a custom object (like `List<Tuple<char, char>>`). You could make a method to make adding easier. Note that `key` and `val` must be unique!

```
private void Add(char key, char val, Dictionary<char, char> dictionary, Dictionary<char, char> reverseDictionary)
{
    dictionary.Add(key, val);
    reverseDictionary.Add(val, key);
}
```

Then use this:

```
Dictionary<char, char> dictionary = new Dictionary<char, char>();
Dictionary<char, char> reverseDictionary = new Dictionary<char, char>();

this.Add('a', '1', dictionary, reverseDictionary);

...

char outputChar;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(inputChar, out outputChar))
{
    // use outputChar
}
```

And for the reverse:

```
char outputChar;
if (reverseDictionary.TryGetValue(inputChar, out outputChar))
{
    // use outputChar
}
```

Comment: oops, I'm still beginner and that code seems to be unfamiliar to me,
but thanks very much, it still looks like very simple than duplicating switch statement!

Comment: What is unclear? I guess lambda expressions are a bridge too far for you ;)

Comment: Lol. What the code does is 1. set up a dictionary; 2. get the value from the dictionary for a specific key. The things you need to do it bind that together with your current code.

Comment: Actually I duplicated the code!
Seems that this is the only way I can understand. I'll remember your code wile I progress in learning C#

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, char> {{'1', 'a'}, {'2', 'q'} /* ... */ };

string name = Console.ReadLine();
string s = name.Where(dictionary.ContainsKey)
               .Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + dictionary[t]);

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Typing `12` will return `aq`. You can also reverse it:

```
string s = name.Where(dictionary.ContainsValue)
               .Aggregate("", (current, t) => current + dictionary.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Value == t).Key);
```

So now you can look up by value and get key. So typing `aq` will return `12`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a dictionary to hold the mapping and then loop through the mapping building up the output string if the current character exists in the mapping dictionary.

The solution below shows using a dictionary of strings that ignore case and culture so that you don't have to have multiple entries for upper and lower case (this is obviously an optional design).

I am also showing the use of StringBuilder, which is far more efficient when appending strings.

```
var MappingDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

MappingDictionary.Add("1", "a");
MappingDictionary.Add("2", "q");

var name = Console.ReadLine();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    var s = new StringBuilder(500);

    foreach (var sourceChar in name)
    {
        string mappedTo;
        if (MappingDictionary.TryGetValue(sourceChar.ToString(), out mappedTo))
        {
            s.Append(mappedTo);
        }
    }
}
```